# InfoBubble z-Index and GMap Marker z-index

Tags: google-maps, z-index, google-maps-markers, infobubble

I am using [InfoBubble](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/infobubble/src/infobubble.js?r=356) to display content in GMap. However the zIndex seems not working since InfoBubble with lower zIndex still block Marker with higher zIndex, anyone encouter similar issue?

The GMap Marker:

```
new google.maps.Marker({
    draggable: true,
    raiseOnDrag: true,
    icon: currentLocationMarkerImage,
    shadow: currentLocationMarkerShadow,
    shape: currentLocationMarkerShape,
    map: map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: getOriginLatLng(),
    zIndex: 11
});
```

The InfoBubble:

```
new InfoBubble({
    /*maxWidth: 300,*/
    borderRadius        : 4,
    arrowStyle          : arrowStyle,
    color               : "#fff",
    borderColor         : '#1e90ff',
    backgroundColor     : '#fefefe',
    disableAutoPan      : disableAutoPan,
    shadowStyle         : 0,
    padding             : 5,
    arrowSize           : 10,
    borderWidth         : 2,
    // hideCloseButton  : true,
    arrowPosition       : 50,
    backgroundClassName : 'phoney',
    disableAnimation    : disableAnimation,
    zIndex              : 10
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infoBubble will always display on top of markers. See:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Initializing

The infoBubble is on the float pane. The markers are on the overlay pane.